# When I use Deployment in Kubernetes, what's the differences between apps/v1beta1 and extensions/v1beta1?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I use the [yaml file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/kubernetes.github.io/master/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/deployment.yaml), which is in the Kubernetes official document,  to create a Deployment in Kubernetes, and it uses `apiVersion: apps/v1beta1` at the top. Then I typed `kubectl create -f deployment.yaml` to create this Deployment, but it occured an error as following:

```
error: error validating "deployment.yaml": error validating data: couldn't find type: v1beta1.Deployment; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false`
```

After some search, I changed `apiVersion: apps/v1beta1` to `extensions/v1beta1`, and then recreate the Deployment with the yaml file, and it worked fine.
So, I wanna know what's the differences between `apps/v1beta1` and `extensions/v1beta1`. Is it pertinent to the Kubernetes version?

```
# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.4", GitCommit:"7243c69eb523aa4377bce883e7c0dd76b84709a1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-03-07T23:53:09Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.4", GitCommit:"7243c69eb523aa4377bce883e7c0dd76b84709a1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-03-07T23:34:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The `apps` API group will be where the v1 Deployment type lives. The `apps/v1beta1` version was added in 1.6.0, so if you have a 1.5.x client or server, you should still use the `extensions/v1beta1` version.

The `apps/v1beta1` and `extensions/v1beta1` Deployment types are identical, but when creating via the `apps` API, some improved defaults are used

Comment: Could you elaborate on the improved defaults?

Comment: Two improved defaults I'm aware of is `progressDeadlineSeconds` defaulting to 10 minutes (vs. not being defined before) and the `DeploymentStrategy` fields  `maxSurge` and `maxUnavailable` being set to 25% each (vs 0 and 1 before).

Comment: Umbrella ticket tracking deprecation of `extensions` - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/43214

Comment: Specific ticket listing the Deployment improvements:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/39683

which lists the 2 default changes mentioned by @TimoReimann